# special set intersection using common link field

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I want to find a way to determine a special flavor of intersection between 2 ordered vectors of file-system path elements as follows.

Each of these vectors contains boost filesystem paths.  The first of these sets  contains file names and extensions. The collection does not have leading path information and the vector cannot have duplicates

```
// these filename+exts need to be in fqpnPathList in order for a match
std::vector<fs::path> uniqueNameList = {
    "file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt" 
};
```

The second of these sets contains a list of fully qualified paths.  This second set can contain duplicate trailing filename+exts

```
// list of fully qualified paths that can contain duplicate filenames+exts
std::vector<fs::path> fqpnPathList = {
    "/tmp/file1.txt", "/abc/file1.txt", "/tmp/file3.txt"
};
```

I need a way of performing a special set intersection that finds all the elements in the **fqpnPathList** that have a filename+ext from **uniqueNameList**

The code below uses a special comparator that operates on elements of each collection that uses just the filename+ext as a link/join field to perform the intersection:

```
    std::vector<fs::path> commonPaths;
    std::set_intersection(
        fqpnPathList.cbegin(), fqpnPathList.cend(),
        uniqueNameList.cbegin(), uniqueNameList.cend(),
        std::back_inserter(commonPaths), fileNameOnlyComp);
```

which results in:

```
"/tmp/file1.txt", "/tmp/file3.txt",
```

The full code listing - which is available live on **[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2f800b36b3d3c23)** is shown below.  From my description of the problem above.

*Could someone show me how to fix the code that performs the intersection to fix or change the intersection code such that I can list all elements in **fqpnPathList** that have filename + extension matches in **uniqueNameList**.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;    
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    for (auto& el : vec)  {os << el << ", "; }
    return os;
}


int main()
{
    // these filename+exts need to be in fqpnPathList in order for a match
    std::vector<fs::path> uniqueNameList = {
        "file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt" 
    };

    std::vector<fs::path> fqpnPathList = {
        "/tmp/file1.txt", "/abc/file1.txt", "/tmp/file3.txt"
    };

    auto fileNameOnlyComp = [](const fs::path& lhs, const fs::path& rhs) {
        return lhs.filename().string() < rhs.filename().string();
    };

    std::sort(uniqueNameList.begin(), uniqueNameList.end(), fileNameOnlyComp);
    std::sort(fqpnPathList.begin(), fqpnPathList.end(), fileNameOnlyComp);

    std::vector<fs::path> commonPaths;
    std::set_intersection(
        fqpnPathList.cbegin(), fqpnPathList.cend(),
        uniqueNameList.cbegin(), uniqueNameList.cend(),
        std::back_inserter(commonPaths), fileNameOnlyComp);
    std::cout << commonPaths << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why this was downvoted, I think my question was pretty clear with example code

Comment: It may be possible to generate the path list with just the names wanted in the first place.

Comment: @greybeard I completely revived the question to simplify it and hopefully clarify my desired results, thanks for your constructive feedback.

Comment: (There still is no explicit question in your question.) (`recursive_`)`directory_iterator`s do not seem to provide an option to "filter" entries. I think the problem is not that you want "multiset behaviour", but that you want it from std::set_intersection. _Don't_ try to tweak `comp` to "achieve" that. I'd probably give turning the allowable `filename+ext`s into a `regex` a try.

Comment: @greybeard happy now? Its got a question rather than a need.  The directory_iterator and its variants are not useful here.  I'm starting to think that some sort of set partitioning may do the trick here - i.e removing elements found via a symmetric set difference or something along those lines.